# When should one specify a python interpreter at the top of the .py script?

Tags: python

As a habit, I always specify a default interpreter at the top of a .bash/.py script. I just noticed that it causes me issues with virtualenv, because the interpreter directs to `/usr/bin/python` instead of the venv one. So I'm thinking, when and when not should one specify an interpreter this way?

Comment: How does it cause you issue with virtualenv? You launch your py script directly like "./app.py"?

Comment: If you want to run the script directly—i.e., `./spam.py`, or even just `spam.py` if you've installed it somewhere on your PATH—then you need a shbang line at the top. But you can use `/usr/bin/env python` instead of `/usr/bin/python`. The manpage for `env` on your platform should explain this. (BSD has a section called "Use in shell-scripts"; GNU… I think it directs you to `info env` or something, with a lot more detail but less conveniently accessed.)

Comment: @Sraw yes. Is that wrong?

Comment: But anyway, this really isn't a question about Python, it's a question about POSIX scripting. I'm not sure whether that means you should ask here with a different tag, or ask on another SE site. But unless you specifically want to focus on some details relating to venvs (in which case you should have the relevant tag for that as well as Python), I don't think this is the right place.

Comment: As abarnert says, if you want to execute your script directly, you need shbang line. If you use `/path/to/python app.py` to launch your script, you needn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script is made executable, your operating system will know which interpreter to use

Given a file named `my_script` that is executable and starts with

- `#!/bin/bash`: your OS will us `/bin/bash` to interpret the script
- `#!/usr/bin/python`: your OS will use `/usr/bin/python` to interpret the script

But one caveat is - as you noticed when using virtualenvs - that people do not necessarily have the same path for their interpreter.

A workaround and a good practise is to use the [env utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) to invoke a command.

`#!/usr/bin/env python` will use the first python found in your path, which in your case will be your virtualenv's python